# Can't edit <html> tag, how to add FB Namespace

Tags: facebook, namespaces, facebook-like

I hope this is the right place to ask this. If not could any of you please tell me where I might get an answer to this question please. I have search everywhere and find nothing.

I'm helping a friend with a site and she is use XSitePro blogging software. XSP does not allow you to edit the  tag but we need to add the FB Namespace to her pages.

Is there any way to add this if the html tag can't be changed?

Thanks,
Terry

Comment: There's a few different methods for a *Like* button.  HTML5, XFBML, IFrame, etc.  I think only the XFBML method requires a new namespace.  Maybe you can try one of the others?

Comment: The tag that AddThis, which is why we need to add the NS, is:

xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"

The problem is how to get the NS to work if it can't be added to the <html> tag>

Is there a way to do it with a div element? Like this:

<div xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
AddThis Code...
</div>

Comment: Can you try something like: `document.documentElement.setAttribute("xmlns:fb", "http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml");`

Comment: Thanks Mike. The setAttribute worked. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer as well..

Answer (score 0):

You can add the namespace to the document through script.  Something like:

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute("xmlns:fb", "http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml");
```